# YouTube embeded video starting at specific time (not working)

Tags: html, video, youtube, video-embedding

I want an embeded video to start at a specific time. In this case at 66 seconds into the video. Hi have tried various versions of the html code below which involves adding `?start=66` or `#t=66s` to the end of the URL but nothing seems to work. Also tried removing `?ecver=1` but doesn't change it. I also tried adding `version=3` to the end of the URL.

I have tried both on Firefox 57.04 and Chrome 63.0.3239.132.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<body>

<iframe width="548" height="308" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Y9OXjY_Yhg?start=66?ecver=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
</head>
```

It just won't start the video at the specific time.

Comment: Well it doesn't work as a URL... how would it work embedded? What's ecver=1? If you remove that it starts at the correct time (it does for me at least).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Y9OXjY_Yhg?start=66?ecver=1

The URL query string *starts* with a question mark, but multiple name=value pairs are separated from each other using `&`

Because you messed that up, you effectively send the *value* `66?ecver=1` for the `start` parameter - not surprising that gets ignored.

The *correct* URL to use here is simply https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Y9OXjY_Yhg?start=66&ecver=1 (or even without the `&ecver=1`, as Jacob H pointed out in comments - if that parameter does not influence another specific setting that you explicitly want to control, that is.)